# What is a starting point/template to build a decentralised app for Ethereum

Tags: ethereum, decentralized-applications

I am interested in building decentralized apps on ethereum and am wondering about the common libraries being used.  For example, I've heard of whisper and swarm but the tutorial I got them from was over three years old and I'm just wondering if anyone knows what are some common libraries for basic and advanced functionality.  Thanks!

Comment: This question is not good ft for StackOveflow format. However I will answer any case, because there is a lot of outdated information and answers and I want to point people to the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Note that when you build a DApp (decentralised application) your fronted directly interacts with the blockchain. There is no server. Thus, you rarely build DApp with any of backend programming language like Python, Java, PHP or C#.

The popular Ethereum JavaScript SDKs include

[Hardhat](https://hardhat.org/)

[Truffle](https://github.com/trufflesuite/)

Client-side frontend libraries are

[Web3.js](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/)

[Ethers.js](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/)

Python, commonly used in data science and analytics, has:

[Brownie](https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/)

[Web3.py](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/)